# Going back from first controller in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITabBarController` as the root view in my application. From here, one of the ViewControllers that the `UITabBarController` shows needs to open up another view with a back button to come back to what is underneath - the `UIViewController` that the `UITabBarController` was showing.

I have created a segue from the `UIViewController` within `UITabBarController` to open up a `UINavigationController` which then shows a new `UIViewController`.

The problem I have is that there isn't a back button to go back before the `UINavigationController` - which makes sense as the views before the navigation controller are not part of the stack.

What's the best way to handle this situation? In this case, I'm just wanting to open a `UIViewController` that can go further screens deep but ultimately I need to be able to have a back button on that first `UIViewController` within the `UINavigationController` to go back to the `UITabBarController`.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to present the navigation itself with

```
self.present(nav......
```

then dismiss it with when you click back button in FirstVC in that navigation

```
self.dismiss.....
```

Comment: self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_name", sender: self) - this is not going to work?

Comment: The issue is that the back button isn't showing in the first VC because it's the first thing in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to simulate navigation controller behaviour in modal presentation, you can achieve this by adding navigation bar to first UIViewController inside UINavigationController stack, then add left bar button item with action

self.dismiss(animation: false)

It will behave as navigation controller and solves your question, but you don't get navigation's controller swipe back from the. box, and transition animation differs.

(In cases like this, I would prefer just modal presentation without camouflaging)

Comment: So does this mean that you wouldn't use a navigation controller at all? Just use modal presentation?

Comment: @sark9012 nope, navigation controller is used, but modal presentation is default and obvious with close button instead back

Comment: @sark9012 by the way it is said to prefer of using custom view controller instantiation and presentation vs using seques